# Javascript Regex replace by group

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose you have this string: `url?param1=something&param2=something&param3=something` which can also be only `url?param1=something`.

How would you do to convert `param1=something` to `param1=anotherthing` ?

I am able to do it this way:

```
var regex = /param1=.*(&|$)/;
var string = 'url?param1=something&param2=something&param3=something';
var newValue = 'anotherthing';
string.replace(regex, 'param1='+newValue);
```

However, I do not like the fact of repeating all the search term, so I'm asking if it is possible to group the needed pattern to replace, in this case would be `.*` and replace only that.

For example, saying that $1 belongs to group 1. This is fictitious.

```
var regex = /param1=(.*)(&|$)/;
var string = 'url?param1=something&param2=something&param3=something';
var newValue = 'anotherthing';
string.replace(regex, $1, newValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var string = 'url?param1=something&param2=something&param3=something';
alert(string.replace(/(param1)([^&]+)/, '$1=newparam1'));
```

if you want to set multiple parameters to the same value

```
alert(string.replace(/(param1|param2)([^&]+)/g, '$1=newparam'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another capture group...

```
var regex = /(param1=)([^&]*)/;
var string = 'url?param1=something&param2=something&param3=something';
var newValue = 'anotherthing';
string.replace(regex, "$1" + newValue);
```

Comment: Hey thanks, your example gives me `"url?param1=anotherthing"` instead of the full url, any tip?

Comment: Whoops, I did not pay attention to your reg exp, it should have been  `/(param1=)([^&]*)/;`